# Only image in tag page

Tags: wordpress, tags, wordpress-theming

I need to customize the tag page. I am using WordPress ver:5.1 with Generatepress theme. I want to get the content from the post without linking to post details page. Also don't need any info about the post here like author, date, category etc.

[This is what is showing right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTTEH.png)

Comment: just check tag.php is in the theme folder or not. If not create tag.php by copying the category.php or archive.php

Comment: tag.php is there but I need to fetch all content from the post but not the comment, author name, categories etc. and yes there will be no link to the post

Comment: can you please share the code of tag.php so I can give you an idea to get the result.